# Using Scrollmagic in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, scrollmagic

I want to use [Scrollmagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic) in an iFrame. Is there a way to make this work?

Example:
http://raet.boldinteractive.nl/staging/iframe.html

The 4th section has a trigger (see indicators)

Comment: What code have you used so far? Can you please show it?

Comment: I just iFramed a working Scrollmagic example. This is the source > http://raet.boldinteractive.nl/staging/samenvatting.html. As you can see it's working if you open it in the browser. When you iFrame this page the ScrollMagic events are ignored.

The code > https://jsfiddle.net/n05p79uf/
(this isn't working in the JSfiddle, but the code is the same as samenvatting.html)

Comment: I'm now trying to use postMessage to send the current scrollTop to the iFrame and there try to update the current scroll position with: http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/docs/ScrollMagic.Controller.html#scrollPos but still without any luck. It doesn't work..